# Case nested case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I am having issues adding another set of conditions to my nested case statement. I have tried re formatting the statement several ways and putting the "END" in different places but i can't seem to get past the ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments error.
I thought i just needed one END per CASE, and that the END needs to come before the else to close out that condition. Is that wrong? If i comment out the last else condition it works fine.

As per the comments below i have tried to straighten up my code and set the correst else and end statements, but i still get the same error. Essentially there should be 5 sets of conditions.

```
    CASE 
    WHEN IND0.M_COM_FUT <>0 AND IND0.M_COM_FUT = IND5.M_COM_IND 
    THEN 
        CASE    WHEN IND5.M_COM_IND = CMIND5.M_REFERENCE 
                THEN
                    CASE    WHEN CMIND5.M_PHYSICAL = PHYS5.M_REFERENCE 
                            THEN PHYS5.M_LABEL 
                    END 
        END 
    ELSE
        CASE    WHEN   IND0.M_UNDRL = IND3.M_INDEX AND IND3.M_IND_LAB LIKE '%NBY%' AND IND3.M_COM_NBY_T = 2 
                THEN
                    CASE    WHEN  IND3.M_COM_FUT = IND6.M_COM_IND 
                            THEN 
                                CASE    WHEN IND6.M_COM_IND = CMIND6.M_REFERENCE 
                                        THEN
                                            CASE    WHEN CMIND6.M_PHYSICAL = PHYS6.M_REFERENCE 
                                                    THEN PHYS6.M_LABEL 
                                            END 
                                END 
                    END
          END          
       ELSE
            CASE    WHEN IND0.M_UNDRL = IND3.M_INDEX 
                    THEN
                        CASE    WHEN IND3.M_COM_IND = CMIND3.M_REFERENCE 
                                THEN
                                    CASE    WHEN CMIND3.M_PHYSICAL = PHYS3.M_REFERENCE 
                                            THEN PHYS3.M_LABEL 
                                    END 
                        END                         
            END
        ELSE
            CASE    WHEN   IND0.M_UNDRL = IND3.M_INDEX AND IND3.M_IND_LAB LIKE '%NBY%' AND IND3.M_COM_NBY_T = 0 
                    THEN 
                        CASE    WHEN  IND3.M_COM_FUT = FUT.M_REFERENCE 
                                THEN 
                                    CASE    WHEN FUT.M_QUOT_FWD= QUOT.M_REFERENCE 
                                            THEN
                                                CASE    WHEN QUOT.M_INDEX = IND0.M_INDEX 
                                                        THEN PHYS0.M_LABEL 
                                                END 
                                    END 
                        END 
            END 
         ELSE
            CASE    WHEN IND0.M_IND_LAB= IND0.M_IND_LAB 
                    THEN PHYS0.M_LABEL
            END 

END AS PRODUCT,
```

Comment: Your title reads `TSQL` which is the SQL dialect used by **Microsoft SQL Server**, yet in the question you state that you are getting an **Oracle** error message. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: yes - you are correct it is Oracle. The new platform is Oracle, the old one is Sybase, hence my confusion

Comment: You have ELSE 2 times in your first case.

Comment: Actually, this statement is a total mess. Some sections will never be used. Maybe you should give us an example of what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

if you format your code better, you should find it have duplicate `else` and miss some `end` too

```
CASE 
    WHEN IND0.M_COM_FUT <>0 AND IND0.M_COM_FUT = IND5.M_COM_IND 
    THEN 
        CASE    WHEN IND5.M_COM_IND = CMIND5.M_REFERENCE 
                THEN
                    CASE    WHEN CMIND5.M_PHYSICAL = PHYS5.M_REFERENCE 
                            THEN PHYS5.M_LABEL 
                    END 
        END 
    ELSE
        CASE    WHEN   IND0.M_UNDRL = IND3.M_INDEX AND IND3.M_IND_LAB LIKE '%NBY%' AND IND3.M_COM_NBY_T = 2 
                THEN
                    CASE    WHEN  IND3.M_COM_FUT = IND6.M_COM_IND 
                            THEN 
                                CASE    WHEN IND6.M_COM_IND = CMIND6.M_REFERENCE 
                                        THEN
                                            CASE    WHEN CMIND6.M_PHYSICAL = PHYS6.M_REFERENCE 
                                                    THEN PHYS6.M_LABEL 
                                            END 
                                END 
                    END 
                ELSE
                    CASE    WHEN IND0.M_UNDRL = IND3.M_INDEX 
                            THEN
                                CASE    WHEN IND3.M_COM_IND = CMIND3.M_REFERENCE 
                                        THEN
                                            CASE    WHEN CMIND3.M_PHYSICAL = PHYS3.M_REFERENCE 
                                                    THEN PHYS3.M_LABEL 
                                            END 
                                END 
                            ELSE
                                CASE    WHEN IND0.M_IND_LAB= IND0.M_IND_LAB 
                                        THEN PHYS0.M_LABEL
                                END 
                            END 
                    END
                ELSE
                    CASE    WHEN   IND0.M_UNDRL = IND3.M_INDEX AND IND3.M_IND_LAB LIKE '%NBY%' AND IND3.M_COM_NBY_T = 0 
                            THEN 
                                CASE    WHEN  IND3.M_COM_FUT = FUT.M_REFERENCE 
                                        THEN 
                                            CASE    WHEN FUT.M_QUOT_FWD= QUOT.M_REFERENCE 
                                                    THEN
                                                        CASE    WHEN QUOT.M_INDEX = IND0.M_INDEX 
                                                                THEN PHYS0.M_LABEL 
                                                        END 
                                            END 
                                END 
                    END 
END AS PRODUCT,
```

Comment: thanks Alex. i thought i could see what you meant and so corrected my code. I have pasted this above. unfortunatley i stil get the same error message. essentially it is not a duplicate else - as there are 5 separate conditions statements, but maybe i am still putting the end in the wrong place?

Comment: @user3432849 I'm afraid yes, maybe you should indent your code, for my code as example, just `case` and `end` is same level, `when`, `then` and `else`, then you should able to identify all duplicate `else` or `end`

Answer (score 0):

Try this to start. I'm not sure what your logic is here, but at least this should run and give you the results I think you are looking for based on your code.

```
CASE
  WHEN IND0.M_COM_FUT <> 0
   AND IND0.M_COM_FUT = IND5.M_COM_IND
   AND IND5.M_COM_IND = CMIND5.M_REFERENCE
   AND CMIND5.M_PHYSICAL = PHYS5.M_REFERENCE
    THEN PHYS5.M_LABEL  
  WHEN IND0.M_UNDRL = IND3.M_INDEX
   AND IND3.M_IND_LAB LIKE '%NBY%'
   AND IND3.M_COM_NBY_T = 2
   AND IND3.M_COM_FUT = IND6.M_COM_IND
   AND IND6.M_COM_IND = CMIND6.M_REFERENCETHEN
   AND CMIND6.M_PHYSICAL = PHYS6.M_REFERENCE
    THEN PHYS6.M_LABEL 
  WHEN IND0.M_UNDRL = IND3.M_INDEX
   AND IND3.M_COM_IND = CMIND3.M_REFERENCE
   AND CMIND3.M_PHYSICAL = PHYS3.M_REFERENCE
    THEN PHYS3.M_LABEL 
  WHEN IND0.M_UNDRL = IND3.M_INDEX
   AND IND3.M_IND_LAB LIKE '%NBY%'
   AND IND3.M_COM_NBY_T = 0 
   AND IND3.M_COM_FUT = FUT.M_REFERENCE
   AND FUT.M_QUOT_FWD= QUOT.M_REFERENCE
   AND QUOT.M_INDEX = IND0.M_INDEX
    THEN PHYS0.M_LABEL 
  WHEN IND0.M_IND_LAB= IND0.M_IND_LAB
    THEN PHYS0.M_LABEL
END
```

If the WHEN statement doesn't match, it automatically goes to the next WHEN.

The first WHEN statement that matches will then ignore all other WHEN statements, even if one or more of the WHEN statement below it would also match.

The ELSE can be used one time after the last WHEN to return a default value if none of the WHEN statements matched.

Comment: yes this does run, thks. So i don't need the ELSE? I thought that was the better way to avoid situations where a match then stopped the other when statements. It still doesn't give me the answers i need, but that might just be my joins and referencing.

Comment: As soon as any THEN is reached the CASE returns the value no matter what else is there. If more than one WHEN can match, you have to put them in order by priority. The first one that matches is always returned.